# Newest badge shown in wrong place in badge tracker

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, badge-progress

When you have [played out the badge tracker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel), the newest badge is still shown, but in the place where the next badge used to be:

[image]

rather than in its original position on the left:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed with the [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/295232):

[image]