# Badge tracker not showing the next badge

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

Usually when I go to a users' profile and look at [the activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity), I can see there a badge tracker which shows the newest badge and next badge - with a progress towards that badge.

Today I have noticed one user profile where the badge tracker only shows the newest badge, but the part with *progress to the next badge* is not displayed. What is the reason for this? Is it simply that the user already has all badges which [can be displayed in the badge tracker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263610/why-arent-all-the-badges-shown-on-the-track-menu)?

Here is my attempt to check [number of trackable badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1236853/users-with-largest-number-of-trackable-badges) for individual users - however, I am not sure whether I have missed some of the badges. Originally I have noticed this in [Glorfindels' profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=topactivity) on this site. Using the above query [on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1236853/users-with-largest-number-of-trackable-badges), I was able to find two users with profiles like this: [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe?tab=topactivity) and [templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef?tab=topactivity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I'm out of badges to track; that's the reason why you don't see a badge tracker there, and the Newest badge appears in a different place than usual. I posted a bug report here: [Newest badge shown in wrong place in badge tracker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341204/295232). This all wouldn't be a problem if you could track the Socratic badge multiple times, as requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271984/295232).