# Make use of the trackable badge space once all are earnt

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, profile-page, badge-progress

I recently earned all of the badges that are trackable over on my main site Science Fiction and Fantasy. I'm not quite sure what I was expecting or if I figured it would be empty but of course, it ended up being empty. See the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of the Badges section from my profile]

This space is pretty empty and could be used for something now, or at least aligning the badge so it's not just floating in the middle of nowhere. I can think of a few options:

1. Use the space to re-track the badges that can be earned more than once.
2. I'm aware that not all badges are trackable due to [performance issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263610/345161) but that was 5 years ago, it might be possible to track these now.
3. Use the space to track an extra tag badge like on the Reputation graph section on the Summary page.
4. Include a history of the last N earned badges similar to the second Badges section from the Summary page of the profile.
5. Include a dancing unicorn with flashing, animated text reading: "CONGRATULATIONS!".

Can we better make use of this space once all of the trackable badges are earned?

Comment: Talk about first world user problems, eh?

Comment: Congratulations! Related: [Badge tracker not showing the next badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347676/295232) (I answered there to track Socratic multiple times, that solves most problems) and [Newest badge shown in wrong place in badge tracker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341204/295232)

Comment: One more possibility is to track the next badge for the meta site.

Comment: The obvious answer is unicorns.