# Badges information is messed up on user profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

For example:

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

[Reported on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409038):

> [image]

This might be related to the recent [`grid`/`grid--cell` → `d-flex`/`flex--item`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/689) migration.

Comment: Just noticed this. Note [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rq5g.png) shows how it used to look. (I've earnt all trackable badges here for reference see [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347885/345161)).

Comment: The "next badge" selection is also messed up (the "X" is towards the top center, instead of the top right).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yep, a report on MSO for that bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409038/select-your-next-badge-ui-element-misplaced

Comment: It seems that [Tag Info - Top Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/responsive-design/topusers) page is misaligned too.

Comment: confirmed/reproduced on Firefox 89.0.2/64/Windows 10.

Comment: This appears to have been a pretty rough change... seems it has [broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jP4Q.png) some userscripts for the moment too :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just merged a hotfix for this one. We were missing flex equivalents for `grid__fl1` and `grid__fl0`. It'll go live soon, and should fix these layout issues.

Comment: Better plan ahead and make flex equivalents for `grid__fl3` and `grid__fl2` too, no? ;-)

Comment: `.grid__infinity+1` too!